# How to count the number of rectangles given an array representing images?

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, edge-detection

[image]

So I have an array that looks like that above. As you can see, we have a lot of potential for the number of rectangles we can have, but if we wanted to gather information from this array that we the optimal number of rectangles is 3 rectangles, one that is (lenxcols) 4x3, one that is 3x3, and one that is 1x3, does anyone know an elegant way to get that information from the image above?

I tried for looping through it to no avail (especially the one for counting rectangles). Ive tried using np.any and np.where, but that is only good for one big rectangle rather than an image that contains many rectangles.

Comment: There are hundreds of web sites with solutions to LeetCode problems.  Have you searched?

Comment: @TimRoberts this is not a leetcode question lol I promise I am not trying to get answers to HW questions or leetcode questions. I am just coding for fun right now, and I am trying to create rectangles for an environment I need for a machine learning algorithm. Can you point me to the right direction for websites? Perhaps an algorithm that I can refer to that I am not aware of that might solve this question? I'm just a bit ignorant as to where I should look.

Comment: LeetCode 84 and 85 are both related to this task.  You might start there.